# JNI LibTorrent Cannot Load Library

Tags: java-native-interface, libtorrent

I want to develop a desktop application using libtorrent(libtorrent-rasterbar-0.16.15) library. The application is written in Java, so I want to use JNI to load the torrent.dll.

First I generated a .h file from javah. Then I wrote a .cpp file for it. Here comes the problem：when I add a line

```
static libtorrent::session gSession;
```

Compilation to dll works well and I got the .dll file. However, when I try to load this torrent.dll in Java through JNI. My application stuck there, without any error. When I remove that line and make the functions just print a few lines, it works.

I got my torrent.dll by bjam:

```
bjam msvc boost=source link=shared boost-link=shared runtime-link=shared
```

bjam version is 1.55.0

Comment: could you add some details on where it gets stuck? inside the session constructor? which line/instruction? (in case you aren't already, you can find this out with a debugger)

Comment: when I tried to use c++ to run libtorrent, everything is fine. I could do the download. But when I want to release it as a JNI dll and load it by JAVA, it just gets stuck at:  System.LoadLibrary("torrent");

Comment: Another thing is that if I put libtorrent::session gSession inside a function, it could work.

Comment: Furthermore, when I tried to put static before libtorrent::session gSession inside a function. My app crashes, and shows assertion fails at src/disk_io_thread.cpp line 117 m_abort==true